# Differential equations system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have found the following example in one of my courses but I don't have any similar exercises resolved so I would like to know how to solve this:

The differential equations system is the following:

$$x_1' = 3x_1 - 2x_2 + e^t$$
$$x_2' = 2x_1 - x_2 + 2e^{2t}$$

a) Write the system in the matriceal form $x' = Ax+b(t)$

b) Determinate the solutin of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the system in matrix form is nearly identical to writing any linear (non-differential-equation) system in matrix form:
$$\begin{cases}
ax+by=c\\dx+ey=f
\end{cases}\iff\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\d&e\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{A}}\,\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{x}}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}c\\f\end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf{b}}$$
The main components are the coefficient matrix $\mathbf{A}$, what I'll call the solution vector $\mathbf{x}$, and what I'll call (for lack of a better name) the right hand side vector $\mathbf{b}$.

In the case of a system of linear ODEs, the same $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ framework can be used. For example, you can rewrite the following general system as:
$$\begin{cases}ax_1+bx_2={x_1}'\\dx_1+ex_2={x_2}'\end{cases}\iff\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\d&e\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{x_1}'\\{x_2}'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}'$$
Your system is different in that there are extra terms that do not depend on $x_1$ or $x_2$. These extra terms can be addressed by introducing another vector to represent any instance of a new term. For example:
$$\begin{cases}ax_1+bx_2+t={x_1}'\\dx_1+ex_2={x_2}'\end{cases}\iff\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\d&e\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}t=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}'$$
This extra term(s) is what your question refers to as $b(t)$.

For your particular system, the matrix form would simply be
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\2&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}e^t+\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix}e^{2t}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}'$$
Solving this system can be done readily via undetermined coefficients. You can find several examples using this method worked out [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx). If you'd like a walkthrough for this particular problem (or are asked to use a different method for solving), feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the walkthrough. Explanation is perfect and yes, I would like if you don't mind a walkthrough for point b aswell.